# When I try to make my profile visible on dice.com, I get error 86. What should I do?

Tags: profile

When I try to make my profile visible in dice.com, it throws an error 86 (not much info other than the error number). I tried contacting customer support, no response.
What should I do to make my profile visible to recruiters ?